# N2 CMS - Protected upload subdirectory?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, n2, n2cms

I can add new directories to the `~/upload` section of my website. Is there a built-in way to protect these directories to be accessible only by certain users/roles?

Comment: how long have you worked with N2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, there is. Within the N2 interface, select the folder for which you wish to control permissions. Once the folder is selected, click the "PERM" button in the toolbar - it's the one with the icon that looks like a key. In the resulting screen, you can customize the permissions according to role.